# Myriad Pro: Chapter number style of the toc with pdfLaTex

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, chapters, minionpro

I use the MinioPro and MyriadPro fonts in my document.

To compile I use the pdfLaTex.

I would like to change the format of the table of contents.

I'm looking for an option to make the chapter numbers and page numbers (of the chapters) in the table of contents bold in Myriad Pro.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[textlf,mathlf]{MinionPro}                       
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}
\usepackage[toc,eqno,enum,bib,lineno]{tabfigures}   

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\chapter{Chapter One} 
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

Here an image of the table of contents:
[image]

Thank you very much for some hints!

@maetra: I tried you code out in a new document with copy-paste but I got a different result. 
[image]
Why do we have a difference?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick, just let the package `tocloft` help you:

> [image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[textlf,mathlf]{MinionPro}                       
\usepackage[toc,eqno,enum,bib,lineno]{tabfigures}      
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{MyriadPro-LF}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}         {\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}     {\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\chapter{Chapter One} 
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried you code out, but it seems to use the standard LaTeX fonts. See the updated question.

Comment: @Fabio Do you have the MyriadPro available? Try to load it via `\usepackage[]{MyriadPro}` before the renewcommand, maybe that helps you.

Comment: @ maetra: I installed the MinionPro and MyriadPro following the guide at http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=8415#p39693. I tryed to run the command     \usepackage[]{MyriadPro} but the program claims it cannot find this map. In the guide is written to not use this command but intead \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{MyriadPro-LF}. Could this be my problem? How can I fix it? How did you install the package?

Comment: @Fabio use fontpro https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro, it will install a package with more options

Comment: @Fabio if your problem is solved you can mark this answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below. If not, try to be more specific in your question so that the community can help you.

Comment: I tried to install the myriad package following the procedure you suggested me, but I was not able to make it working. I downloaded the LCDF Typetool, I installed the Cygwin, but I did not find the package "texlive-font-fontutils" and I do not know how to make it running...
Could you help me?